# Parsing Parentheses in Propositional Logic Program

Tags: java, parsing, recursion, parentheses

I'm working on translating a propositional logic statement to conjunctive normal form. The issue I'm having is parsing through the possibly complicated parentheses levels. The question I need to solve is the right order and I think recursion should be used to solve the inner parentheses first before moving outward but I can't figure out how to implement my ideas. The program is written in Java. Can anyone help?

Comment: I had some funky system where I tried working semi-interatively. It tried to start at the beginning, find the first open parens and take everything until the first close parens and recursively feed it through until there was only one open parens and one close parens. Then it would attempt to solve. The problem I had was that in solving, sometimes more parens are needed so the method would get caught in a loop. That and I hadn't finished the logic on it so I couldn't test it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982087/how-to-convert-statements-into-cnf/15982562?noredirect=1#15982562

Comment: [Similar question .... So, do we have to write code using like IF-ELSE for all the possible inputs eg: (Not(Not A)), (NOT(NOT(OR(A B)))][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982087/how-to-convert-statements-into-cnf/15982562?noredirect=1#15982562

Answer (score 1):

Can you give an example of the statement you're converting to CNF?  I'm thinking you mean there are parentheses in the starting logic statement, but it would help to see.

In the meantime, I'll say you don't need recursion... but a stack would be very helpful : )  Push items and their mathematical operations onto the stack, then pop them off and act on them when appropriate.  Since it's homework I won't go into too much detail, but you'll find that you'll push-push-push-pop-multiply-push-push-pop-add-pop-divide... use the stack as a way of focusing on the current operation.

An investigation into Postfix Notation is also relevant and may help... even the wikipedia article on it will give you some ideas (though there are absolutely more computer-science-oriented articles out there).

*Disclaimer:  I put no thought into the number or order of those pushes and pops in my example : )*

**Update**

You don't need more than one pass through the data, and you can convert to CNF on the fly.

You're heading in the right direction, so some help/hints:

- Use two stacks, one for the operands and one for the operators.
- When you have two operands and an operator, you pop the operands, apply the operator, and push the result back as a new (consolidated) operand
- The advantage of postfix is that you can do your conversion on the fly... for example, when you encounter a →, apply a ¬ to the operand stack and push a ⋁ onto the operator stack

Taking a reduction of your example:

```
F→(E⋀(A→B))
```

The first steps of the conversion looks like this (I'm assuming you've got the underlying logic-conversion rules down pat, and that it's just the code you're working out):

```
F→(E⋀(A→B))
¬F⋁(E⋀(A→B))
¬F⋁(E⋀(¬A⋁B))
```

In CNF postfix, it will look like this:

```
F¬EA¬B⋁⋀⋁     // (Parentheses are obviated in postfix notation)
```

To get there, read through your initial logic statement in one pass from left to right...  Push operands onto the Operands stack, and operators onto the Operators stack.

As you apply the Operators, pop the required operands from the Operands stack, apply the operator, and push the resulting string back to the stack as a new operand.

Closing parentheses or lower-precedence operations trigger the pop-apply-push.  The whole thing looks like this:

```
                                      Operand        Operator
                                       Stack          Stack
                                     ----------     ----------
Read F:  Push onto Operand stack     F ........      ..........

Read →:  On-the-fly conversion (→ becomes ¬⋁)
  Unary Operator ¬ pops F from Operands; applies it; pushes back to Operands
                                     ¬F .......      ..........   
  Push ⋁ onto the op-stack           ¬F .......      ⋁ .......    

Read (:  Discard    

Read E:  Push onto Operands stack    ¬F E ....       ⋁ ...... 
Read ⋀:  Push onto Operators stack   ¬F E ....       ⋁⋀ .....

Read (:  Discard                    
Read A:  Push onto Operands stack    ¬F E A ..       ⋁⋀ .....

Read →:  On-the-fly conversion (→ becomes ¬⋁)
  Unary Operator ¬ pops A from Operands; applies; pushes back to Operands
                                     ¬F E ¬A .       ⋁⋀ .....
  Push ⋁ onto Operators stack        ¬F E ¬A .       ⋁⋀⋁ ....

Read B:  Push onto Operands stack    ¬F E ¬A B       ⋁⋀⋁ ....

Read ):  Triggers Operators/Operands pop; applies; pushes back to Operands 
        (After, there are three operands on the Operands stack)
                                     ¬F E (¬A⋁B)    ⋁⋀ ....

Read ):  Triggers Operators/Operands pop; applies; pushes back to Operands
        (After, there are two operands on the Operands stack)
                                     ¬F (E⋀(¬A⋁B))  ⋁ ....

No more reads:  Final Operators/Operands pop/apply/push (result is output)
                                    ¬F⋁(E⋀(¬A⋁B))
```

**Caveats and notes:**

This is just a start in the right direction... you'll have to deal with issues like operator precedence (i.e. do you push and act later, or pop and act now).  You'll find your decision is based on the next character you read (and not on the closing parenthesis, as I've implied above).

It sounds more complicated than it is... pseudo-code for the above wouldn't be more than 12-15 lines.  However, there are complexities I haven't addressed... the <--> function will have to be modeled in a way similar to → is above... you'll have to take this line of thinking and implement all of the conversion rules.

Implied parentheses can trip you up, e.g.

```
6 * (8 * 6) + 4
```

is really

```
(6 * (8 * 6)) + 4
```

If you don't handle operator precedence correctly, you might end up with something like

```
686*4+*
```

Which gives you 312, instead of the correct answer (292).

If you have trouble reading the unicode logic symbols in this post, let me know; I can redo it with standard characters, but it reads so much nicer in uni : )

HTH,
James

PS:  A nifty little applet illustrating postfix is here: 
http://fac-web.spsu.edu/cs/faculty/bbrown/web_lectures/postfix/

Comment: An example would be something like this: F-->(E/\ (A-->B)<->(C-->D))

Where "-->" stands for implication, "<->" is a biconditional, and "/\" stands for a conjunction.

Comment: Okay, then everything I said applies.  You want to read up on stacks, and postfix notation... general idea here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postfix_notation#Explanation - I can offer more help if you need it, if you are still stuck or scratching your head... just want to give you the opportunity to think the idea through a bit before giving you the 'answer'.  It's great mental exercise to read a little and think of ways to apply it... you'll need that ability to be finely-honed by the time you get out of school : )

Comment: I really appreciate the help. So I've looked at both stacks and postfix and I'm not quite sure how postfix is used here or why it is preferable to the original format. I did begin using the stacks though and I'm still trying to work out the kinks. I have it trying to stack things up with the whole problem on the bottom, then the next set of parentheses so the stack would look something like:
 F-->(E/\ (A-->B)<->(C-->D))
then
E/\ (A-->B)<->(C-->D)
... and when it reaches the bottom, it solves and goes back up. That's the idea anyway. I'm not sure if I'm implementing in the best way though.

Comment: I've updated my answer to give you a better understanding of the next step... it looks complicated when explained, but you'll find the solution is very simple and elegant.  Whole programming languages are based on stacks and postfix : )  To answer your question, the postfix notation is just a means to an end, and looking at my update, you could probably get by with just understanding stacks.  Postfix is the mathematical connection between stacks and algebraic equations, though; understanding it may be what finally makes the whole thing click : )

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
parseRestOfString (int openParens, String rest) { 
    c = rest (0);
    if (c == ')' && openParens == 0) ...
```

Does that give you a hint?

Comment: I think so. One question about your pseudocode: Is the colon after "String" an assignment or a shorthand for a "for-loop" or an array of Strings?

Comment: It's a low-on-concentration mixture of Java-like `(int openParens,` and scala like , `rest: String)`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

[Recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)

[JavaCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaCC)